# How to use downloaded properties to change UI in swift

Tags: swift, download, grand-central-dispatch

I would like to have the table view of my application have dynamically edited row heights depending on the image that is downloaded. The problem is that when I try to access the size property of the image in the table view controller after dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is called the image is still nil. The images are all being loaded in the model file under a dispatch_main.Async() closure. What is a good strategy to go about implementing this dynamic row height code.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: Please show the code you have and how you are trying to get it working.

Comment: You don't need to know the size of the image before the cell is constructed to have cells with varying/dynamic sizes, just build your cells to be self-sizing (using constraints).

Answer (score 0):

Quick thing to try: in viewDidLoad you can put:

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Depends on your constraints though

Comment: Ive tired but it just makes all the cell content disappear

Comment: oh sorry to hear. Auto-layout is a tough beast to master. check your image view content mode, top constraints, bottom constraints...

Comment: Thank you for all of your help I am going to keep playing around with it more I think you are correct.